# Launch exe file from project

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, relative-path, process.start

In a WPF project I have a block which launch application using:

```
 Process.Start(url);
```

If it throws an error I would like the application to offer to install the exe the sits on the part of the application folder.
The problem is that I am unable to direct to relative folder in the project in order to launch the application.
Would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: It's hard to actually decipher what you mean from this question.  You have a URL (HTTP?) which will launch a web browser.  Can you explain things clearer please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Ensure that your program path is correct at all times.

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "D:\Program.exe";
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName("D:\Program.exe");
proc.Start();
```